# how to pass control from one function to other in C++

Tags: c++, function, return

How to pass control from one function to another in C++?

Basically, I've a function A which takes the input from the user and calls of a function of the user's choice. it can simply be done by calling the desired function using the switch case construct but by this the control will go to the other function and after its execution control will return to function A, but I don't want that. Function A should be terminated at the time of calling of the other function.

Comment: You would simply return from function A after it called the other function.

Comment: A should be a value type function and you should start other functions according to its return value. otherwise, it will become a spawning function which should use a parallel processing where you lose the simplicity.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux maybe post your comment as answer - i don't think there's anything else to add :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::function` for that:

```
void B();
void C( int );

std::function<void()> A()
{
    switch( userInput() ) {
       case 'B' : return &B;
       case 'C' : return std::bind( C, 123 );
    }
    return std::function<void()>{};
}

int main()
{
    auto f = A();
    if( f ) f();
}
```

this will execute either function `B()` or `C(123)` based on user input after `A` terminates.

Comment: This seems like a very round-about way of doing something very simple.

Comment: This is what OP wants, I do not want to question his/her requirements

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you can do as follows.

You can return the function `A` by passing the user input to the other function( `other_functions_here(int& user_input)` ), where you will process the switch cases/ other small functions according to user input.

In this way, you can simple call `function_A()` in the main simply as follows.

However, you should be really careful about the exceptions what you may have to face, while coding this way. Furthermore, the debugging also would be difficult.

```
#include <iostream>

int fun1() {  return 1; }
int fun2() {  return 2; }

int other_functions_here(int& user_input)
{
   switch(user_input)
   {
      case 1: return fun1();
      case 2: return fun2();
   }
   return -1;
}

int funcction_A()
{
   int some_value;
   std::cin >> some_value;

   return other_functions_here(some_value);
}

int main()
{
   int result = funcction_A();
   (result != -1) ? std::cout <<  result :
                    std::cout << "Invalide user input" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I understand what the OP is asking, they would like to see `case 1: return fun1(); case 2: return fun2();`